# How to import class from a Python package directly

Tags: python, class, package

My current package looks something like this:

```
package_repo/
  package/
    __init__.py
    module_one.py
    module_two.py
  tests/
  setup.py
```

Inside the `module_one.py` I have `ClassOne`,and inside the `module_two.py` I have `ClassTwo`. Now, if I want to import `ClassOne` into some other module, I write `from package.module_one import ClassOne`.

Is it possible to import `ClassOne` directly from `package` as in `from package import ClassOne` or `import package as pkg` and then use classes as `pkg.ClassOne()`? If yes, how to do it? I am asking because that is just more elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the __init__.py file in your package, you can declare and initialize anything you want, including imports!

So, write inside it this:

```
from module_one import ClassOne
from module_two import ClassTwo
```

Doing so, now those classes will be known and can be imported directly from the package, as:

```
from package import ClassOne, ClassTwo
```

And yes, you can also do it like:

```
import package as pkg

pkg.ClassOne()
```