# Importing the classes from a python module directly

Tags: python

I have a python module I am writing that has the structure:

```
top_level_module/
    __init__.py
    sub_module1/
        __init__.py
        Class1.py
        Class2.py
    sub_module2/
        __init__.py
        Class3.py
```

The capitalizations there are correct. This structure was chosen by someone else but they are set on keeping it like that (I believe they are used to C++ or Java naming). I want to be able to import the classes easier than a bunch of consecutive
`from top_level_module.sub_module1.Class1 import Class1` statements. Is there a way to do this that is reasonable?

I currently have a classes.py in a couple modules that just import all the classes so I can at least do:
`from top_level_module.sub_module1.classes import Class1, Class2`
but it just seems wrong. I would rather use **init**.py somehow, but I do not want to block the ability to import the modules names ClassX and only allow the import of the classes within them.

I understand that the question is similar to [How to import class from a Python package directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75627149/how-to-import-class-from-a-python-package-directly) but I think it is different enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the `top_level_module/sub_module1/__init__.py` file, you can import the classes from `Class1.py` and `Class2.py`

```
from .Class1 import Class1
from .Class2 import Class2
```

and of course in the `top_level_module/sub_module2/__init__.py` file, you can do the same for `Class3.py`

```
from .Class3 import Class3
```

now, you can import the classes directly from the sub-modules without having to explicitly specify the file names and the `__init__.py` files act as a bridge between the top-level module and the classes within the sub-modulesand, something like this :

```
from top_level_module.sub_module1 import Class1, Class2
from top_level_module.sub_module2 import Class3
```

**update:**
when you import a package,python looks for an `__init__.py` file in the directory and if it finds one,it executes the code inside the `__init__.py` file, so it allows you to define what gets imported when you import the package!

in your example,if you want to import `sub_module1` as a package and also import the classes within it,you can modify the `__init__.py` file in `top_level_module/sub_module1`

```
from .Class1 import Class1
from .Class2 import Class2

__all__ = ['Class1', 'Class2']
```

as you see `__all__` variable is a list that specifies the names that should be imported when you use the `from sub_module1 import *` syntax and by default,python only imports names that do not start with an underscore,so by setting `__all__` to include the class names,you can now import the classes directly from `sub_module1` or import the package itself!!!

let me give you an example :

```
from top_level_module.sub_module1 import Class1, Class2
from top_level_module.sub_module1 import sub_module1

#imported classes
obj1 = Class1()
obj2 = Class2()

#imported package
obj3 = sub_module1.Class1()
obj4 = sub_module1.Class2()
```

good luck !

Comment: Does that completely block the ability to import the package Class1 as a package? 
I'm worried doing that will bother others on the project.

Comment: @Tristan, No, importing the classes in the `__init__.py` files does not block it, let me update my answer for you to better approach !